# Are there any issues with charging an pre-USB-C iPad with a high-wattage power adapter and a USB-C/Lightning cable?

Tags: ipad, charging

Specific configuration:

- iPad Pro 10.5" (2017)
- Anker Nano II 65W charger adapter
- MTAKYI MFI-certified USB-C-to-Lightning Cable

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no issue there. The iPad will never draw more power from the charger than what it can handle.